# Distribution of the Normal Force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

Is there an equation that gives you how the normal force is distributed? In particular, I am considering a basic example with a rectangular object at rest on an inclined plane. I think the biggest part of the normal force is applied at a distance down the incline from the center of mass of the object equal to the coefficient of friction times the distance between the object's center of mass and the surface.  I think this case is basically 2D. How do you find a model of the different amounts of force between the object and the surface? Or if that is just really super complicated, how do you find the maximum amount of force at that point/line from 3 sentences ago, or at least what kind of math is used?

Also, please let me know if I am phrasing things poorly or if there would be a good source to learn about this.

Comment: Force is a vector quantity. Pressure is a scalar .Pressure, is defined as an external force divided by the area over which the force acts; If you are  talking about a given object with a given area, how could there be different amounts of  pressure ?

Comment: Thanks I changed it to stick with saying force.

Comment: I only watched the beginning but maybe this would interest you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ME0OyUdwP6Y

Comment: [rELATED](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/543443/where-does-normal-force-shift-to)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are thinking of definitely could be made into a coherent set of things to do/solve. However, it quickly spirals out of control once you look at how the actual real world physics deviates from the idealisations we are making.

In particular, you are assuming that this rectangular object is perfectly flat, as is the inclined plane. Neither could be true. In reality, you can take microscopic pictures of those surfaces and see that they are jagged. The forces are concentrated on the spots where the jagged parts mesh with each other.

Then consider an idealisation whereby the perfectly flat rectangular object is propped up on the inclined plane at only two points. Then by considering principle of moments, you can figure out the forces. Simply move where the contact points are, and you can get a distribution of forces.

It will be a lot of work, when in fact it does not matter what the distribution is, as long as all the relevant properties are obeyed.

Answer (score 6):

You can say some things about the force, mainly that the torques from all the forces must sum to zero since the object is at rest.

But otherwise, no.  The specific forces depend on the specifics of the surfaces.  Imagine having two surfaces engineered to be very flat.  But there is a tiny, tiny rock between the surfaces.  A huge force will be concentrated on that point (with some other forces near the edge).

You could assume that the surfaces are nearly flat and the pressure across the entire area is nearly constant.  But for real surfaces, it may not be.

In other words, there are many possible force distributions that are all consistent with the object remaining at rest.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct. In general, for a flat-to-flat contact, you can assume the contact normal is concentrated at the edges. There will be two contact normals because the part is can't rotate as well as interpenetrate.

[image: fig1]

And now you apply the balance of forces and torques to find the values of the contact normal $N_A$ and $N_B$ as well as the friction $F_A$ required to keep the block stationary

Looking from a rotated coordinate frame along the ramp you have

$$ \begin{aligned}
 N_A + N_B - W \cos \theta &= 0 \\
 F_A - W \sin \theta &= 0 \\
 \tfrac{L}{2} N_B - \tfrac{L}{2} N_A + \tfrac{H}{2} F_A & = 0
\end{aligned} $$

which is 3 equations and 3 unknowns (the two normal forces and friction). The solution is

$$ \begin{aligned}
 F_A &= W \sin \theta \\
 N_A &= W \left( \tfrac{1}{2} \cos \theta + \tfrac{H}{2L} \sin \theta \right) \\
 N_B &= W \left( \tfrac{1}{2} \cos \theta - \tfrac{H}{2L} \sin \theta \right) \\ \end{aligned} $$

Please note that the difference between $N_A$ and $N_B$ is due solely to the height of the center of mass above the ramp $\tfrac{H}{2}$.

You can even calculate the tipping condition, which happens when $N_B=0$ which leads to the requirement that $H \leq L \cot \theta$.

Comment: Putting normal forces at the edges of the block is mathematically convenient, but I don't see how it represents the physical reality. Surely, a pressure sensor affixed to the bottom of the block does not read zero everywhere except the edges.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie - having run many FEA simulations with contacts this idealization is near reality. It depends on the materials involved, but most of the contact pressure moves to the edges on a flat-to-flat contact. In reality, the center part might have 1-2 MPa of pressure, while the edges close to 1000 MPa. And mere millimeters from the edge the pressure drops to the middle values. In my world, we call this "edge stress" condition and mathematically the value of pressure is _infinite_ at the edges. The book "Contact Mechanics" by K.L Johnson does an analysis showing exactly this.

Comment: One is reminded of the "boundary layer" behaviour in fluid dynamics. Trying to mathematically study this is a headache (see asymptotic analysis).